# Ubuntu Live on Pendrive: How can I default booting to Ram Test?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, default

I would like to create some **Ubuntu Live pendrive** for booting Ubuntu, but most often **testing RAM**:

[image: Ram Test]

So, as long as the **most usual** behavior of this boot manager would be the RAM testing, I would like to configure the boot manager to make this one to be the **default boot** option.

Is it possible?

Comment: May be but not sure here have a look at this [BootToRAM in ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootToRAM).

Comment: Well, @vembutech , maybe I was not clear enough about the Ram Test I am wanting to perform. I have edited the original question to add an image.